# JQUERY swap div value for select box value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to contemplate the concepts of swapping content for a div from a chosen select box value.  So for instance here is my code and let's say I select All Sizes.  I would like for that string to replace the Employer Size string from the class out:

```
<div class="selectdiv">
  <select class="selectboxdiv" id="ddlEmployerSize">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="All_Sizes">All Sizes</option>
    <option value="0_99">0 – 99</option>
    <option value="100_499">100 – 499</option>
    <option value="500">500+</option>
    <option value="1000">1,000+</option>
  </select>
  <div class="out">Employer Size</div>
  <span class="icon-caret-down"></span>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#ddlEmployerSize').change(function(){
        $('.out').text($(this).find('option:selected').text())
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/27B66/)